# Html navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to html so I want to learn how a dropdown was build step by step.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

li .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn"> Home 
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Home sub 1</a>
    <a href="#">Home sub 2</a>
    <a href="#">Home sub 3</a>
    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but I get the result before `Home sub 1` there is a blank line and its like a link. I cant post the picture for now there is a problem in uploading image. But I will add it on my edit later when it is fixed

EDIT 1: As you can see when I hover there is a black like a link in the dropdown menu.
[image]

Comment: You cannot wrap a div inside an anchor tag!

Comment: @athimohan what do you mean?

Comment: you have placed a block element (`<div>`) within an inline element (`<a>`). The blank link is because you have made all the `li a` as `display: block`

Comment: @athimohan HTML5 says that you can do this as long as there are no interactive elements within it

Comment: you want a dropdown on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code for this one

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"> Home </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Home sub 1</a>
            <a href="#">Home sub 2</a>
            <a href="#">Home sub 3</a>
        </div>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that you had a `<div>` tag inside your `<a>` element and without proper formatting and/or styling, you are not going to get what you expect/want.

Comment: you are right that solved it!, but is it possible if I want the dropdown content to take the whole width of the webpage? how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

just put the `div` outside from `a` like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn"> Home </a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Home sub 1</a>
        <a href="#">Home sub 2</a>
        <a href="#">Home sub 3</a>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you are right that solved it!, but is it possible if I want the dropdown content to take the whole width of the webpage?

Comment: add `.dropdown-content {width:100%;}` to your css